What are the degrees of freedom for performing a 1-sample weighted t-test
I have 7 years of observations relating to mortality experience on a pool of lives. I assume each year's experience is independent of the other years. For each year, we have an expected number of deaths and an actual number of deaths. I want to perform a weighted t-test on the ratio of actual to expected number of deaths to test if the A/E is not equal to 1.
The weights represent a measure of how credible the experience is in that year.
I can calculate the weighted sample mean x_bar and this article (https://seismo.berkeley.edu/~kirchner/Toolkits/Toolkit_12.pdf) explains how to get the weighted sample variance.
I can also calculate the appropriate test statistic by replacing root(n) with root(sum of weights squared / sum of squared weights).
My question relates to the critical value and the degrees of freedom. I'm not sure how to calculate the degrees of freedom. My intuition is that the degrees of freedom should simply be 6 because we have 7 independent observations but I'm not sure.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

There's no precise degrees of freedom; the statistic will not have a $t$ distribution even if the data are Normally distributed.
However, if you think of the df as measuring the uncertainty in the denominator of the statistic, df=6 is likely to be optimistic.   Using $df=n-1$ where $n$ is the definition you use for the test statistic is probably better.
Finally, you'd likely be better off working with the number of deaths as the random variable and modelling it as having a Poisson distribution given the expected number, or something similar (details depending on the details of your situation)
